# Bind form control to radio group and text area in angular 4 and above

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

Technologies and versions:
angular:4.4
material: beta12
reactive form

I have a scenario where user can choose one option and upon selecting one of the options, user has to enter text in textarea (disabled until selecting that option).
[image]

On selecting none text area should be disabled and and on yes text area should be enabled.
I am using reactive form where code goes like this

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start">
<mat-hint align="start" fxFlex="1 1 30%" fxFlex.xs="1 1 100%">
  <strong>Functional hardware dependencies:</strong>
</mat-hint>
<mat-radio-group fxFlex="1 1 15%" fxFlex.xs="1 1 100%" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="0.5rem" [formControl]="CRFormGroupData.controls.functionalHWDependencies">
  <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="none">None</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="yes">Yes, namely</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div fxFlex="1 1 55%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="1 1 100%">
    <div fxFlex="1 1 auto"></div>
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="1 1 75%" floatPlaceholder="never" fxFlex.xs="100%">
      <textarea matInput [formControl]="CRFormGroupData.controls.functionalHWDependencies" placeholder="Please define the dependencies"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my controller

```
CRFormGroupData=this.fb.group({functionalHWDependencies: [''],
  functionalSWDependencies: ['']});
```

OUTPUT:
value should be "none"-> when option selected is none
value should be whatever typed in textarea -->when user selected other option)

There might be a chance to have 3 to 4 options with more text area as well.
So i am trying to figure out best approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a controlForm, you can try:

```
this.yourControlFormToDisable
  .reset({value: '', disabled: false});
```

it resets your form with a disabled state.

And this will be executed if you listen the change of your radio button with:

```
(change)="yourFunction($event)"
```